# Using .NET Guid as mongodb document id

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm trying to use .NET Guid as document id for my mongodb documents. The problem that I face now is that .NET Guid bytes are inverted in mongodb id. So I can't fetch newly inserted document with a query like this:

```
_collection.AsQueryable().Where(user => user.Id == id)
```

I think the invertion of bytes happens because of ToByteArray implementation. So, does anybody know any good solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my mistake. The query should look like this:

```
_collection.AsQueryable().SingleOrDefault(user => user.Id == id)
```